# Rounding up different numbers in php

Tags: php

I have different numbers in my code.

For example I want to `1466521` rounded up to `1500000`  or `13422` rounded up to `14000` or `4387` rounded to `4400`

How can I round up every number in php?

Comment: Show us what you have tried? Did you try and google this? I'm fairly certain that there's a native php function for this, do some research.

Comment: Something like this: [working Example](https://3v4l.org/NLaDe)

Comment: i tried with `ceil(1466521 / 10000) * 10000`  shows  `1500000`  ,but what about the other numbers length

Comment: you need some dynamic things, let me try for you.

Comment: @amirali, i make an answer fro you.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple but logical task...use below code

```
function rounded_fun($num){
    $num_length = strlen($num);
    $devide_num = 1;
    for($i=2;$i<$num_length;$i++){
        $devide_num = $devide_num*10;
    }
    $rounded_num  = ceil($num / $devide_num) * $devide_num;
    return $rounded_num;
}



echo rounded_fun(1466521); //1500000
echo rounded_fun(13422); //14000
echo rounded_fun(4387); //4400
echo rounded_fun(12345); //13000
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) you can achive your desired result.

```
if( !function_exists('ceiling') )
{
    function ceiling($number, $significance = 1)
    {
        return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
    }
}
$num = 4387;
$round = (strlen($num)-2);
$roundfraction = pow(10, $round);
echo ceiling($num, $roundfraction); //output 4400
```

for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

other alternative can be [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function:

```
$num = 123456789;

echo round($num,0); // whole number - prints 123456789
echo round($num,-1); // ten - prints 123456790
echo round($num,-2); // hundred - prints 123456800
echo round($num,-3); // thousand - prints 123457000
echo round($num,-4); // ten thousand - prints 123460000
echo round($num,-5); // hundered thousand - prints 123500000
echo round($num,-6); // million - prints 123000000
echo round($num,-7); // ten million - prints 120000000
echo round($num,-8); // hundred million - prints 100000000
echo round($num,-9); // billion - prints 0
```

For general you can use belo solution:

```
$num = 1466521;
$round = (strlen($num)-2)*-1;
echo round($num,$round); // prints 1500000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = '13422';
$ex = 1;
$ex = str_pad($ex, (strlen($str)-1), 0);
echo round(ceil($str/$ex), PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) * $ex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$str = 4387; // 13422, 1466521 
$len = pow(10,(strlen($str)-2)); // Here 2 present 2nd position of your digit. It will change according to your need.
$result = ceil($str/$len) * $len;
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num    = '1454856';
$base= pow(10, strlen($num)-2);
echo ceil($num/$base) * $base;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different method to acheive this logic.

You can use this function to make your logic but this will convert your number to string and will ultimately return a number.

```
function CustomRound($varNum) {
     $varNum = (string)$varNum;
     $len = strlen($varNum);
     $varLastNum = (int)substr($varNum,2);
     if($varLastNum>0) {
         $varFirstTwoDigit = (int)substr($varNum,0,2);
         $varFirstTwoDigit++;
         return (int)str_pad($varFirstTwoDigit,$len,0);
        }
return $varNum;
}
```

Second method is to check how many numbers are there after two digits and them multiply the first two digit with the number generated by `pow(10, $strLength-2)`.